# Import only specific attributes to nominatim

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim

I'm trying to set up my own nominatim server. For this I used a Dockerimage (https://github.com/helvalius/nominatim-docker/issues).

So I want to import all the german data but this seems to be a huge amount of data.

So according to my special needs I don't need all information which is stored. I only will send requests to the server with a street, a house number, a city and a zip code.

Because the request comes from our database I know that this information is available.

So I hope there is a way I could only import the needed data to save some disk space and server power too.

Is there a way to do this? Or is there a way to get predefined data with my needs?

Answer (score 1):

It should be sufficient to import only the data for Germany in your case. See [country and area extracts](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts). Nominatim will import all relevant data required for geocoding. This is slightly more than just "street, a house number, a city and a zip code" since [administrative boundaries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative) are often necessary to determine which city a specific place belongs to.